# Работа ScrollView при передвижении пальца не по нему

Tags: прокрутка

Как сделать так, чтобы ScrollView прокручивался при движении пальцем не по нему, а в произвольной точке дисплея?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
    android:src="@drawable/corner8509"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ugolokravn1" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollVertical2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView8"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:fadingEdge="none">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:src="@drawable/left8509"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ugolokravn2" />
</ScrollView>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollHorizontal2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView8"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView8"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:fadingEdge="none">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:src="@drawable/top8509"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ugolokravn3" />
</HorizontalScrollView>

<com.pavel.sortament.VScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:id = "@+id/scrollVertical1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scrollHorizontal2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrollVertical2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/scrollVertical2"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:fadingEdge="none">

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id = "@+id/scrollHorizontal1"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:fadingEdge="none">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:src="@drawable/content8509"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ugolokravn4" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: У Вас планшет? Покажите разметку

Comment: Нет, не планшет. Добавил разметку. Мне нужно, что бы все эти скроллы работали не зависимо от того, веду я пальцем по ним или нет